# SQL - How to ORDER BY different columns in one query

Tags: sql, sorting, sql-order-by

I'm trying to order my records by different columns, not just one. I can order my records using ORDER BY, but what if I want to order some data in a table sorting them by different columns?

For example, I've got a table with `AGE`, `MONEY` and `NAME` columns.

- When I click on AGE, I want to do `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY age DESC/ASC`
- When I click on `MONEY`, I want to do `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY money DESC/ASC`
- Finally if I want to order by `NAME`, I want to do `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY name DESC/ASC`

The result should be something similar to this:

[image]

I looked for CASE but I didn't find what I need, but I think that I have to you use something like the switch statement. Does this exists in SQL? I could do this with PHP too, but I can't understand how.

Thanks!

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: your image really doesn't explain how you want to order your results

Comment: as per your edit: that can't be done at the RDBMS level, do that with your reporting tool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two basic options:  you can order in the db or you can order in the front end.  If you are paging your data, you want to do it in the db but if it is only a few rows, you could do it either place.  Remember, **the front end cannot sort rows you did not pull from the database**.

To sort in the front end, please consult the documentation for the programming frameworks you are using.

To sort in the back-end, you need to send a new db query every time you want a different sort.  This makes sense since you may not have all the rows retrieved you want to display.  So from your question you understand the SQL, so you just need to send it on each click.  Again, consult the documentation of the programming frameworks you are using for help in making that happen.